# Liferay: Get Unique session id on every login

Tags: session, jboss, liferay

I'm writing a code to keep audit trails of every login on my application. For that, I'm getting session id from **AuditRequestThreadLocal** object by using **auditRequestThreadLocal.getSessionID()**.

**Problem is: It is giving same sessionId for user on every login(multiple login of same user).**

Regarding that, I fetch sessionId from **HttpRequest** but It also returns same sessionId for that user on every login.

*P.S. (In case of **TOMCAT**, It seems working fine but In the case of **JBOSS** it is returning same sessionId)*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution:

inside the portlet.properties, set **session.enable.phishing.protection=true** :

```
#
# Set this to true to invalidate the session when a user logs into the
# portal. This helps prevents phishing. Set this to false if you need the
# guest user and the authenticated user to have the same session.
#
# Set this to false if the property "company.security.auth.requires.https"
# is set to true and you want to maintain the same credentials across HTTP
# and HTTPS sessions.
#
session.enable.phishing.protection=true
```

Comment: Enabling phishing protection causes error in case of guest user; basically It is giving null value of  SessionError. So, I can't able to enable this property. Still, searching any new way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try apply in your portal-ext the next properties:

```
session.enable.phishing.protection=true
session.phishing.protected.attributes=OPEN_ID_CONNECT_SESSION
```